# JSON Object with Slashes in it

Tags: json, serialization, javascriptserializer

I am serializing to a json object using:

```
public static string ToJson(this object obj)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return jsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
}
```

However when I'm populating a hidden field, I'm getting the slashes with it:

> "[{\"ImageLink\":\"\",\"ShowOnHomePage\":null,\"Type\":\"AdListItem\",\"Key\":null,\"Title\":\"dsafdsaf\",\"Url\":\"fdsafdsa\",\"ContentSummary\":\"\u003cdiv\u003efdsafdsa\u003c/div\u003e\"},{\"ImageLink\":\"\",\"ShowOnHomePage\":null,\"Type\":\"AdListItem\",\"Key\":null,\"Title\":\"hddfg\",\"Url\":\"dsaf\",\"ContentSummary\":\"\u003cdiv\u003efdsafdsa\u003c/div\u003e\"},{\"ImageLink\":\"\",\"ShowOnHomePage\":null,\"Type\":\"AdListItem\",\"Key\":null,\"Title\":\"asfd\",\"Url\":\"asdf\",\"ContentSummary\":\"\u003cdiv\u003eafds\u003c/div\u003e\"}]"

How would I properly get rid of the \" and replace them with just " ???

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: The result looks like a string. So you have to escape the " characters. When the complete string is being evaluated you still want the object to contain the surrounding double quotes. Or did I get something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slashes are Javascript string escape characters.

\" -> "    so you can have a quote with-in a quote.

This is true for most all C-style languages (C, C++, C#, Java, etc)